# Center an element in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

No matter what I try, I can't center something in Bootstrap navbar, any solutions for it?

I've tried adding a div, using `margin:0 auto;` or `margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto;`, used `center-block` class. Nothing works, why is so hard to achieve something so simple I can't understand, what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the current code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark main-nav">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Website Name</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rates</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As of Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 (flexbox), [here is the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42181069/171456) for horizontal navbar center.

Comment: What exactly were you trying to center in particular?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4, there is a new utility known as `.mx-auto`. You just need to specify the width of the centered element.

Ref: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Diffferent from Bass Jobsen's answer, which is a relative center to the elements on both ends, the following example is absolute centered.

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar bg-faded">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-logo mx-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Brand</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And CSS:

```
.navbar-logo {
  width: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Not ideal as it requires setting a specific logo width. Also, no longer works in alpha 6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714674/bootstrap-4-center-list it still works

Answer (score 85):

***Update Bootstrap 5 (2021)***

The Navbar still uses flexbox so alignment works the same way as Bootstrap 4.

***Update Bootstrap 4.1+***

Bootstrap 4 the navbar now uses flexbox so the `Website Name` can be centered using **`mx-auto`**. The left and right side menus don't require floats.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark main-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Website Name</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rates</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[**Navbar center with `mx-auto`** Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/J9rL11Tf7h)

If the Navbar only has a single `navbar-nav`, then `justify-content-center` can also be used to center.

### ***EDIT***

In the solution above, the `Website Name` is centered *relative* to the left and right `navbar-nav` so if the width of these adjacent navs are different the `Website Name` is no longer centered.

[image]

To resolve this, one of the flexbox workarounds for **absolute centering** can be used...

**Option 1 - Use position:absolute;**

Since it's ok to use absolute positioning in flexbox, one option is to use this on the item to be centered.

```
.abs-center-x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Navbar center with **absolute position** Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/BC2gFdZ9fb)

**Option 2 - Use flexbox nesting**

<strike>Finally, another option is to make the centered item also `display:flexbox` (using `d-flex`) and center justified. In this case each navbar component must have `flex-grow:1`</strike>

As of Bootstrap 4 Beta, the Navbar is now `display:flex`. Bootstrap 4.1.0 includes a new `flex-fill` class to make each nav section fill the width:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark main-nav">
    <div class="container justify-content-center">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-fill w-100 flex-nowrap">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-fill justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Center</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-fill w-100 justify-content-end">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[Navbar center with **flexbox nesting** Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/4XNoJE4T3j)

Prior to Bootstrap 4.1.0 you can add the flex-fill class like this...

```
.flex-fill {
   flex:1
}
```

As of 4.1 `flex-fill` is included in Bootstrap.

---

[**Bootstrap 4 Navbar center demos**](https://www.codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v)
[**More centering demos**](https://www.codeply.com/go/4XNoJE4T3j)
[Center links on desktop, left align on mobile](https://www.codeply.com/go/wWZKVllCei)

Related:
[How to center nav-items in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738067/how-to-center-nav-items-in-bootstrap/43738936#43738936)
[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/)
[How move 'nav' element under 'navbar-brand' in my Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077119/how-move-nav-element-under-navbar-brand-in-my-navbar)

[image]

Comment: Option 2 worked for me! I have 2 questions if you don't mind:
1. What is flex-grow doing?
2. How can I increase the width of the center element? I'm looking to use the center element as a search bar.

Comment: Option 1 worked for me! Just remember to add the ml-auto tag to the text on the right hand side as ZimSystem points out in his CodePly demo.

Comment: Have you tested your solution with Bootstrap 4 beta? According to the following [article](https://medium.com/@lukaszholeczek/how-to-upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-bootstrap-4-beta-d43b4210f2a3) you need to replace `.navbar-toggleable-sm` to `.navbar-expand-sm` and `.bg-inverse` to `.bg-dark`.

Comment: How do you use the navbar collapse with this?

Comment: Anyway to align the menu items after a side navigation bar so the menu starts where the main content starts on the x-axis?

Answer (score 2):

use
mx-auto will do the job

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
.nav-tabs > li{
    float:none !important;
    display:inline-block !important;
}

.nav-tabs {
    text-align:center !important;
}
```

Comment: can you please provide your url? or any demo link. i will checkout there.

Comment: try this.     .navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14146967/1596547, now you can use:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light main-nav">
<div class="container text-xs-center">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-left">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="display: inline-block;">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Website Name</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rates</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

apply `text-xs-center` on your container and set `display: inline-block;` for your list.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem; the anchor text in my Bootstrap4 navbar wasn't centered. Simply added `text-center` in the anchor's class.

Comment: @Mohsin did you try <input class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;"> with an input of display: block? or class="text-center"

Answer (score 0):

make new style

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
.center-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
.center-nav li{
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}
```

Replace website name UL with below

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav center-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Website Name</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

from the docs

> Navbars may contain bits of text with the help of .navbar-text. This class adjusts vertical alignment and horizontal spacing for strings of text.

i applied the .navbar-text class to my `<li>` element, so the result is

```
<li class="nav-item navbar-text">
```

this centers the links vertically with respect to my navbar-brand img

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue to center the text. It was fixed by the navbar-text

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="navbar-text">
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + userName,"Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, 
htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", onclick = "javascript:return false;" 
})*@
  
 <p style="color: #999999;"> Hello  @userName</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why Not using bootstrap utilities. here is the code

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="your-logo"/></a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mx-auto justify-content-md-center" id="collapsibleNavbar" >
    <ul class="navbar-nav col-md-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li> 
    </ul>
  </div> 
</nav>
```