# Centering the navbar content in Bootstrap 4 (alpha 5)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to center the navbar content in Bootstrap 4, alpha 5. I have been googling a bit, and I guess there might be some trick involving `d-block` and `mx-auto`.

However I cannot find out how to center the navigation links so that they are total in center, not just adding a container around them.

Sample navbar code I am playing with:.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle if you like](https://jsfiddle.net/losol/19vcjwo4/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Centering Navbar items is simpler in Bootstrap 4, and doesn't require additional markup.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active text-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item text-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item text-center">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown text-center">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown link
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

<kbd>[Bootstrap 4 Center Navbar Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/f5gFK47WQr)</kbd> (updated for **v4.0.0**)

If you need to center only specific elements, such as the Brand or Links, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181069/171456)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use css to accomplish this, since bootsrap's "mx-auto" class can take care of this for you. You can simply add the following to your ul class:

more info on horizontal centering in boostraps docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/

Comment: I think part of your answer is missing?