# Bootstrap 4 centered navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

using new Bootstrap 4 v4.0.0-beta.2 and I cant find a way to center the content in my navbar. I have tried everything! Any ideas? Code below.

The earlier answers is about the ALPHA releases of bootstrap 4 and Ive tried them all! and their solutions does NOT work.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/img/frontpage/logotest.png">logo
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Take a lookt at flex: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering the navbar content in Bootstrap 4 (alpha 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516523/centering-the-navbar-content-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-5)

Comment: That answer does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center content in responsive bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18777235/center-content-in-responsive-bootstrap-navbar)

Comment: THATS BOOTSTRAP 3

Comment: Specify what doesn't work, could you also provide your inline CSS, if you used any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this code. it works with bootstrap 4. I just added `d-flex justify-content-center` to navbar-collapse.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="/img/frontpage/logotest.png">logo
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-center" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ">
            <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://codepen.io/sodhisaab/pen/OObOZP

Comment: When the navbar collapses the navigation items are still visible?

Comment: @user1594257 If you remove the `d-flex` class, but keep `justify-content-center` it should work. `d-flex` overrides the `display: none` style when the navbar is collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

### Navbar at center using bootstrap 4

> you need to add only .justify-content-center class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">my website</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">about us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact us</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```