# Bootstrap 4 center navbar brand with collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

I cant seem to figure out how to get both the right links and left link to both collapse. Right now only the right hand side link collapses.

```
<nav id="topNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    Menu
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">NavBar</a>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: all the menu items must come in one <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"> to make the collapse functionality work.. Toggle button will only target 1 collapse div not multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Currently in alpha 6, the collapse only supports a single target.</strike>.

**Update Bootstrap 4.1**

You can absolute position the brand on larger screens, and use a single collapse for the 2 navbars.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-brand
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Sh05HDqIh1

Also see:
[Center an element in Bootstrap 4 Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867603/center-an-element-in-bootstrap-4-navbar/42181069#42181069)
[How to center nav-items in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738067/how-to-center-nav-items-in-bootstrap/43738936)

Comment: This overlaps the Menu Buttons :(

Comment: How so? Do you have an example?

Comment: @ZimSystem The example is in your code, would suggest that you try and click any of your navigation links, and you might realise that every single time you're clicking the logo instead. Easily solved with a `z-index: -1;`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer and example for Bootstrap 4.1.1

Comment: What if you want to be able to click either the brand or the navigation?

Comment: This somewhat works now, but for some reason the brand moves with the menu when it's opened. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: you can use margin: 0 auto; in the place of  position and left properties.

Answer (score 3):

You should **wrap** both the **menus ul** in one `navbar-collapse` div. **Toggle Menu button** will only **target one collapse** div **not multiple**. As **earlier** there were **two navbar-collapse**.

> Here is code you should use.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav id="topNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    Menu
</button>
  <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">NavBar</a>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav id="topNav" class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    Menu
</button>
  <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">NavBar</a>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code posted by ZimSystem will overlap the menu items due to having 100% width and might clash with click events etc. A better option would be to use left instead of width.

```
.navbar-brand
  {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: The issue with click was easy to resolve in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43499579/171456) by removing `width:100%`