# brand between left and right navigation in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
 <nav class="navbar-toggleable-sm" role="navigation">
      <div class="container justify-content-center">


          <div class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered">Brand</div>




          <ul class=" navbar-nav float-left">
            <li class = "nav-item"><a class=" nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class = "nav-item"><a  class=" nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class = "nav-item"><a class=" nav-link"  href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class=" navbar-nav float-right">
            <li class = "nav-item"><a class=" nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class = "nav-item"><a class=" nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class = "nav-item"><a class=" nav-link" href="#">Link</a></li>              
          </ul>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

I have started to learn bootsrap 4 here i want my navigation like the first three links to left and others to right of my brand of logo and that whole container be justified as center also.

Comment: You'll find the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42181069/171456) and in the other dups.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#">BRAND</a>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```