# How can I center a list with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building an app with the Bootstrap 4 beta. This app is really basic at the moment and has a single inline list. I'm trying to center this list horizontally in the middle of the screen. As shown in this [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/gJ7ge23jq0), I thought `justify-content-center` would do it. However, that did not work. I tried the other centering classes I saw listed [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) without any luck. My list looks like this:

```
<div>
  <ul class="list-inline justify-content-center">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 5</li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I center an inline list with the Bootstrap 4 beta?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `text-center` *OR*,

Use `mx-auto` inside a flexbox container (`d-flex`)..

https://www.bootply.com/6COUMfNrEU

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <ul class="list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 5</li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

**How to centering works in Bootstrap 4...**

`text-center` is used for display:inline elements

`mx-auto` (auto x-axis margins) will center display:block or display:flex elements that have a defined width, (%, vw, px, etc..). Flexbox is used by default on grid columns, so there are also various centering methods...

Center text or inline elements: `text-center`

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">i'm centered</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">i'm centered!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Center display:block or display:flex: `mx-auto`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="//placehold.it/200x150?text=mx-auto">
    </div>
</div>
```

Columns can also be centered with: `mx-auto`, because `row` is `display:flex`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
        <h6>I'm .col-4 centered</h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Centering](http://www.codeply.com/go/SOSvvKpLOc)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use bootstrap classes then you can use `row`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-inline d-flex justify-content-center">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 5</li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Otherwise, Simply `text-align:center` is enough.

```css
ul.list-inline {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful with `.row`. It's meant to be used only to contain columns (`col-*`) because of negative margins.

Comment: @ZimSystem Thank you for reminding me. But I think wrapping the `.row` into the `.container` is enough.

Comment: `.row` should only be [used to group columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Your solution only works because row is adding `display:flex`, so it would be better to use the `d-flex` class instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the class `text-center` which actually centers the block in the screen using the `text-align` property within bootstrap css.

```
<div>
   <ul class="list-inline text-center">
      <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">Item 4</li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">Item 5</li>    
   </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` for ul because `justify-content-center` works with flexbox

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <ul class="list-inline justify-content-center">
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 1</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 2</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 3</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 4</li>
    <li class="list-inline-item">Item 5</li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap provides classes for this (`d-flex`). You shouldn't be writing custom CSS.