# positioning nav-links around a centered nav-brand - BOOTSTRAP

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a Navbar using bootstrap. 
right now I'm having a problem with centering the nav-links on both sides of the nav-brand.

The following is my HTML code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light ">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">True Space</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-item-center" id="navbarMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item right-to-brand">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Captin Recruitment</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item left-to-brand">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Parts</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

CSS code:

```
.navbar {
  background-color: rgba(172, 238, 255, 0.103);
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav .right-to-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 300px;
}

.navbar-nav .left-to-brand {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 200px;
}
```

this comes out like so:
[navbar problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2VdD.png)

I want all the items to be aligned in one line,
I tried using display: inline-block; but it didn't work

I'm really new with this stuff so I would love to get some help with this.

Thank you!

Comment: try setting `top` value on `absolute` items like `top:30px` or in `%`

Comment: Welcome, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-or-right-aligned-items/20362024#20362024 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867603/center-an-element-in-bootstrap-4-navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this real quick from the Bootstrap example code, without any extra CSS, just by adding the classes (ml-auto, mr-auto) of bootstrap in a logical way and changed the position of the logo. If you want the logo not between the menus in responsive version, you could add a second logo and control visibility also by default classes.

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            <a class="navbar-brand ml-3" href="#">MY BRAND</a>

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>


          </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: Preview of the menu]