# Center heading in navbar - bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a responsive navbar and would like to center the heading in it. None of the other functionality or positioning needs to change other than the heading "Title".

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-end">
  <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-sm-block" href="#">Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block text-center order-0 order-md-0 w-25">Title</div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav w-50 order-2 order-md-0" id='navbarSupportedContent'>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success ml-auto mr-2 d-block d-sm-none">Always Show</button>
</nav>
```

Please advice me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 the navbar now uses flexbox so the Title can be centered using mx-auto. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33867603/center-an-element-in-bootstrap-4-navbar#:%7E:text=Bootstrap%204%20the%20navbar%20now,menus%20don%27t%20require%20floats.&text=If%20the%20Navbar%20only%20has,also%20be%20used%20to%20center.) answers, more bootstrap [navbar](https://www.codeply.com/go/kTGlK9Axdk/bootstrap-4-navbar-center-links-examples)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark justify-content-between">
  
  <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-sm-block order-0 w-50 mr-0" href="#">Brand</a>
 
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
 
  <a href="/" class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block text-center order-md-1 w-25">title</a>
         
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse dual-nav order-md-2 w-50">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-success ml-auto mr-2 d-block d-sm-none">Always Show</button>
</nav>

<br><br>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark main-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Website Name</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rates</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```